# Track pg_dump process id and trigger an error while it fails

Tags: bash

When pg_dumpall is running I track that process by `kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null` and print dots:

```
pg_dump --host=xxx --dbname=xxx --port=xxx --username=xxx -C --file=xxx.sql --table=xxx & PID=$!
while kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null; do
        echo -n '.'
        sleep 1
done
```

when dump fails (whatever problem is e.g. due to `kill -9 <pid>`) I need to print an error like below `err_quit "$(timestamp) [ERROR] Database dump FAILED. Exiting.."`:

```
echo "$(timestamp) [INFO] Start dumping ${DBNAME}"
if ! pg_dump --host=xxx --dbname=xxx --port=xxx --username=xxx -C --file=xxx.sql --table=xxx; then
    err_quit "$(timestamp) [ERROR] Database dump FAILED. Exiting.."
 fi
```

The question is how can I combine all of that: start a process in the background, track that pid and print dots.. when pg_dump fails print an error and exit.

I tried to make it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

function dumping {
pg_dump --host=xxx --dbname=xxx --port=xxx --username=xxx -C --file=xxx.sql --table=xxx &
}

function checking {
dumping
PID=$!
echo "$PID"
while kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null; do
        echo -n '.'
        sleep 1
done
}

if ! checking; then
echo "error"
fi
```

but `checking` function returns `exit code 0` and `if` statement won't work properly.

Debug log of that:

```
$ bash -x dots.sh 
+ checking
+ dumping
+ PID=121251
+ echo 121251
121251
+ kill -0 121251
+ echo -n .
.+ sleep 1
+ pg_dump --host=xxx --dbname=xxx --port=xxx --username=xxx -C --file=xxx.sql --table=xxx
+ kill -0 121251
+ echo -n .
.+ sleep 1
+ kill -0 121251
+ echo -n .
.+ sleep 1
+ kill -0 121251
+ echo -n .
.+ sleep 1
pg_dump: terminated by user
+ kill -0 121251
+ return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `wait <pid>` to recover the return code of a background process.

See: Bash man-page `wait`:

> wait [**-fn**] [id ...]
>
> Wait for each specified child process and return its termination status. Each id may be a process ID or a job specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are waited for.
>
> If id is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero.
>
> If the **-n** option is supplied, wait waits for any job to terminate and returns its exit status.
>
> If the **-f** option is supplied, and job control is enabled, wait forces id to terminate before returning its status, instead of returning when it changes status.
>
> If id specifies a non-existent process or job, the return status is 127. Otherwise, the return status is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.

Lets implement the background `wait`, print dots while the `pg_dump` runs, and check the return code of the `pg_dump`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function term_bg_jobs() {
  # Registered as a SIGINT handler to make sure that
  # we don't leave running background jobs behind
  # when this script is interrupted with Ctrl+C
  local -a job_ids
  read -r -d '' -a job_ids < <(jobs -p)
  [ "${#job_ids[@]}" -gt 0 ] && kill "${job_ids[@]}" 2>/dev/null 
}

function dumping() {
  local -i pg_dump_pid pg_dump_rc dot_pid

  # Start pg_dump as a background task
  pg_dump --host=xxx --dbname=xxx --port=xxx --username=xxx -C --file=xxx.sql --table=xxx &
  pg_dump_pid=$! # Get the PID of background pg_dump
  printf $"%s in progress, please wait:\n" 'pg_dump'
  while :; do # while true infinite loop
    printf '.' # print a dot
    sleep 1    # every seconds
  done &# run in the background
  dot_pid=$!           # save the background process id of the dot print

  wait -f $pg_dump_pid # wait for the dump to finish
  pg_dump_rc=$?        # save return code of the dump
  kill $dot_pid        # stop the dot print that was running in the background
  echo                 # just for newline after the dots

  if [[ $pg_dump_rc -gt 0 && $pg_dump_rc -lt 127 ]]; then
    printf $"%s ended with error code %d\n" 'pg_dump' "$pg_dump_rc"
  fi
}

# Install our Ctrl+C trap handler to terminate background jobs
trap term_bg_jobs INT

dumping
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that helped! But ```wait``` command does not support any options any more? In my case I've got an error that options are not supported. https://ss64.com/bash/wait.html

Comment: OK. That feauture (```wait -f```) is available since ```bash-5.0```. I am running on older bash 4.2.

Comment: It is probably ok to not use the `-f` switch while waiting for the `pg_dump`, as it is unlikely to change its status until it actually terminates.

Comment: I have TERMINATED output when killing job.. so I did it like that:
```sh
      pg_restore_pid=$! # Get PID of the background psql process
      while kill -0 $pg_restore_pid 2>/dev/null; do
         printf '.'
         sleep 3
      done
      wait "$pg_restore_pid" # Wait for function to finish
      pg_restore_rc=$? # Save return code of the restore process
```